# Adding Two External Displays via USB-C adapter

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I recently purchased a type-c to dvi and hdmi adapter (Selore &S-Global) so I could use this to plug-in two external monitors to my Asus Vivobook with Ubuntu 20.04 on it.  Unfortunately, it seems my system does not even recognize that anything is plugged in.  Is there another step I am missing here that would get this to work?  I already updated my kernel to the latest version, and that did not help.  The laptop I am using has a 10-th gen Core i3 processor with integrated graphics.  Also, the hub has a usb port on it that does seem to work, so the hub is working to some extent, at least.

Here is the output of lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:56dd IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2109:8888 VIA Labs, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 2109:0100 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Thanks.

Comment: When the hub is plugged in, show the output of `lsusb`.  It might need a driver installed for the adapter to function for the DVI/HDMI output

Comment: Thanks, I added that to my question

Comment: You're trying to plug in two different monitors from a single USB-C port that's adapted to one DVI and one HDMI port?  Yeah, that's probably not going to work... I would be willing to bet the adapter explicitly says it doesn't work that way.  And two displays probably exceeds the bandwidth on the port, and your laptop CPU might not support any more than one external display either.

Comment: According to Intel, it should support up to 3 displays: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196588/intel-core-i3-1005g1-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-40-ghz.html  When you say it won't work that way, should work if only one display is plugged into the adapter?  This doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Just because the CPU is capable of 3 displays, that says nothing about the capabilities of your motherboard, ports, or USB bus.  And adapters make everything muddy.  Are you sure this USB port can even support a display to begin with?  Try to connect a monitor using a native cable (no adapters)

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one kind of USB-C to HDMI/DVI adapter, and there's more than one kind of USB-C port, if the two don't match then they won't work together.

The kinds of USB-C ports include USB only, USB with Thunderbolt, USB with DisplayPort, USB with Thunderbolt and DisplayPort, and more variations that are not very common.  This means that there's many kind of adapters for getting HDMI and DVI video from these ports.

If the USB-C port is USB only then to get video requires a USB to video graphics controller.  A common brand of such controllers is DisplayLink.  DisplayLink is different from DisplayPort.  DisplayLink is a brand of USB graphics controller, DisplayPort is an audio/video protocol.  If your USB-C port supports only USB then you will need a DisplayLink USB-C adapter to get video from that port.

If your USB-C port supports DisplayPort then a USB-C/DisplayPort to HDMI and DVI adapter will work.  A DisplayLink adapter will also work but since a DisplayPort to HDMI/DVI adapter is less expensive and more capable than a DisplayLink adapter it would most often be wise to take advantage of this.  I suspect that you have a USB-C/DisplayPort to HDMI/DVI adapter plugged into a port that is USB only.

There are USB-C ports that support Thunderbolt.  Thunderbolt on a USB-C port often means the port also supports DisplayPort but this isn't always the case.  A DisplayLink adapter will work on these ports but a Thunderbolt to HDMI/DVI adapter will often cost more and do more.  These contain a full fledged graphics GPU, are often quite large and built as a kind of dock that will provide power to a laptop and provide USB, Ethernet, and/or other ports.

So, look at the kind of USB-C to HDMI/DVI adapter you have.  Does the documentation for it say the host must have DisplayPort or Thunderbolt to work?  Does the documentation indicate that it has a DisplayLink USB to video controller?

Now, look at the documentation for your computer.  Does it indicate the USB-C port is USB only?  Does it indicate the USB-C port supports DisplayPort?  Does it indicate the USB-C port supports Thunderbolt?

DisplayLink adapters will work on any USB-C port that supports the USB protocol, which will be 99.999% of them.  DisplayPort based adapters will only work on USB-C ports that support the DisplayPort protocol.  This confuses people because even though they are not wanting a DisplayPort output the adapter will use the DisplayPort protocol to get audio and video from the computer then convert that to HDMI, DVI, VGA, or whatever.  It's difficult to say with any certainty how common DisplayPort support on USB-C is now, but I'm guessing 50/50 is not far off.

Thunderbolt on USB-C does seem uncommon on computers not made by Apple.  Computers that support Thunderbolt will likely have the Thunderbolt icon near the USB-C port, and on some computers not all USB-C ports will support Thunderbolt.  It's unlikely you have a Thunderbolt adapter since these are something of a specialty item, if you have one then you will likely be quite aware of it.  Because Thunderbolt rarely comes on a computer that doesn't also have DisplayPort, your adapter is not working, and the most common USB-C video adapters will be DisplayLink or DisplayPort, then it's unlikely your computer has Thunderbolt.

HDMI on USB-C is a thing but I'm not aware of any computers that support this, and adapter cables for this will be rare.  MHL is another audio/video protocol used on USB-C but this seems limited to smart phones, portable video games, and other electronics smaller than a laptop or tablet computer.  It's possible you picked up a USB-C/MHL to HDMI/DVI adapter by mistake.

Again, the most likely explanation for your trouble is that your adapter cable requires DisplayPort support on USB-C and your computer does not support this.  If that's the case then the quickest way to resolve this is by getting a dock, dongle, or cable that has a DisplayLink video controller.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with docking station for two monitors as well. I don't know what exactly did it, but I managed to make both monitors work, although initially only one was responding.

1. Plug in both monitors into the docking station via USB-C
2. Connect the docking station to the notebook
3. In the settings, make all monitors have the same resolution. Mine was 2048x1440
4. Disconnect the docking station from the notebook, and reconnect it back after a 30 sec.

If I did the 2nd step and then the 1st step, the second monitor would always refuse to recognize the docking station. If I did not do the 3rd step, the notebook would see 3 monitors, but one of them would always be just a black screen. The 4th step is just to make sure that you can disconnect your notebook, and reconnect it without resetting the display settings again.

Comment: I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 with a "QGeeM"-branded USB-C -> HDMI + HDMI + VGA hub. Ubuntu actually detected the resolution of both monitors correctly (1920 x 1080), but it had one set to 60.00 Hz and the other to 74.55 Hz. Setting both monitors to 60.00 Hz, Applying settings, and unplugging/replugging the USB-C connector got both monitors to work at the same time.